# Postfix status bounced unknown user

Tags: centos, email, postfix

**The Problem**

As root, I send an email to John.

```
mailx john@example.com
```

The maillog contains status bounced, unknown user john.

> postfix/local to=john@example.com, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced unknown user: "john"

**My Setup**

On a clean install of CentOS 7, I install Postfix.

```
yum install postfix
```

In the /etc/postfix/main.cf file, I use domain example.com.

```
mydestination = example.com
```

In the /etc/postfix/main.cf file, I set users home mailbox to Maildir/, and there is no mailbox command.

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
```

In the /etc/postfix/main.cf file, I remove the comment from local recipient maps, to query local user accounts.

```
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd:byname $alias_maps
```

I create a new user, John.

```
useradd john
```

I update the aliases database.

```
newaliases
```

I restart Postfix.

```
systemctl restart postfix
```

I verify Postfix is running.

```
systemctl status postfix
. . . active running
```

John's account exists in /etc/passwd.

```
john:x:1002:1002::/home/john:/bin/bash
```

The postconf command shows that Unix can be used to query users. This should mean that `local_recipient_map = Unix:passwd.byname` can be used to query users.

```
]# postconf -m | grep unix
unix
```

I am not sure if this is the problem, but the following command produces no output.

```
postmap -q john@example.com unix:passwd.byname
```

My question should not be a duplicate of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377813/postfix-status-bounced-unknown-user-myuser), as the solution provided in this similar post is to set `mydestination` to `localhost localhost.$mydomain`. When I do this, and then restart Postfix, I get the same exact error in the mail log, "bounced - unknown user john.doe". Also, in this other post, there is a much more developed Postfix setup, with mysql. My setup is very simple.

Comment: Did you issue the `newaliases` command? ... [Postfix aliases](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about the `newaliases` command. I have issued the `newaliases` command as root, restarted Postfix, send a new email to john.doe@example.com as root, and still the issue persists, where "bounced unknown user john.doe" appears in `/var/log/maillog.`

Comment: This may or may not be related to your problem, but dots are a bad idea in UNIX usernames.  That's because `john.doe` used to be interpreted as user `john`, group `doe`.  Some utilities still do that to this day.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Satō Katsura. I have replaced `john.doe` with `john`, and have verified the issue persists. I have updated my post to show `john`.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your entire config and full logs.  Which is why debugging Postfix configurations almost never works on [unix.se].  I really suggest using the `postfx-users` list instead.